# Redirect user to another country site if first visit

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to work out the PHP required to enable the following;

If a user visits our .co.uk site for the first time from outside of GB, then redirect them to their appropriate country site. But, if they visit the .co.uk site again, then we don't redirect them.

I've got the following code to check the session to see if it's the user's first visit, then redirect them  to .de site. But obviously this is not properly checking their country of origin and redirecting them appropriately. I'd need to redirect FR users to .fr and DE users to .de etc. So i'm wondering if someone can help with the missing parts to do the proper redirect based on country if it's their first visit?

```
<?php

session_start(); 

if(isset($SESSION['views'])){
    $_SESSION['views']++;
}else{
    $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
    header("location: http://www.domain.de");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: So? What have you tried?

Comment: so store relative machine / ip and redirect !

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully make it more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You should check HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header to check the language that user uses and session or cookie to check if it's first vist.

Having these two variables makes you able to redirect user to proper page.

Check this url for more details: http://www.phptutorial.info/scripts/languages.php

Comment: Hi. I don't think I can use Language because some people in Germany might have their browser as English but we want them to go to DE site anyway if it is their first visit to the UK site.